# error binding <checkbox> property CheckedChanged to a Command

Tags: .net, xaml, mvvm, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I am developing .NET MAUI application. Have faced with such problem with <checkbox and its property CheckedChanged = "". I am using MVVM Community Toolkit. I have View page, its xaml.cs file and ViewModel.

View page:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="PlumbingCompany.Page3_GeneralInfo"
             Title="3. General Info">

                <StackLayout Margin="20,20,30,0">
                    <Grid Margin="10,0,0,0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="80" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"   
                               Text="Is There a Previous Repair Tag? *"  
                               FontAttributes="Bold"
                               LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>

                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" 
                               Text="Is There a Previous T/O Tag? *"
                               FontAttributes="Bold" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>

                        <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" IsChecked="{Binding Is_previous_repair_tag_YES}" CheckedChanged="{Binding IsPreviousRepTagCommand}"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  Text="Yes" TextDecorations="Underline" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        <CheckBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" IsChecked="{Binding Is_previous_repair_tag_NO}"    />
                        <Label Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" Text="No Tag" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" TextDecorations="Underline" FontAttributes="Bold" />

                        <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row ="1" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" IsChecked="False"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Text="Yes" TextDecorations="Underline" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        <CheckBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row ="1" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" IsChecked="True"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Text="No Tag" TextDecorations="Underline" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackLayout>
```

xaml.cs file

```
using PlumbingCompany.Data;
using PlumbingCompany.Views;
namespace PlumbingCompany;

public partial class Page3_GeneralInfo : ContentPage
{
    public Page3_GeneralInfo(Page3ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
 [ObservableProperty]
    private bool _Is_previous_repair_tag;//////////////////////////////////

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool _Is_previous_repair_tag_YES = false;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool _Is_previous_repair_tag_NO = true;


    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool _Is_previous_TO_tag;//////////////////////////////////////

    [RelayCommand]
    public void IsPreviousRepTag()
    {
       
            Is_previous_repair_tag_YES = true;
            Is_previous_repair_tag_NO = false;
    }
```

When I try to compile program it drops the next error:
"XFC0009    No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "CheckedChanged", or mismatching type between value and property."

I can't understand why CheckedChanged doesnt want to Bind with "IsPreviousRepTagCommand"

:)

I tried to change my code, without using Comunity Toolkit, but any way it didn't worked.

In microsoft checkbox documentation "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/checkbox" is mentioned that you can bind CheckedChanged with event handler.

Comment: `CheckedChanged` is an **event** and needs to have an event handler defined in the code behind.  You cannot bind an event to a command.  However, there is an `EventToCommandBehavior` you can use to convert an event to a command

Comment: Thank You for answer, Jason. I have one more question, please. If I just create an event handler in my ViewModel, how can I bind CheckedChanged with it? CheckedChanged="{Binding EventHandler}" doesn't works. Thank You!

Comment: As I already told you, **you cannot bind event handlers**.  Event handlers must be defined in the code behind.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MAUI event to command behavior command binding to viewmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76165029/maui-event-to-command-behavior-command-binding-to-viewmodel)